# libpcap - pcap_findalldevs returns NULL on MacOSx

Tags: c, macos, pcap, libpcap, tcpdump

I am trying to detect all network adapters on my machine (OSx 10.8). So I have this small, typical piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    pcap_if_t *alldevs;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs, errbuf);
...
}
```

When I execute this the linked-list: pcap_if_t is empty and the errbuf is clear as well. Could this be a permissions issue? I would expect something to be written to the errbuf in that case but that is an assumption. Any other reasons why this would happen? And yes.. I have network adapters available on this machine :)

Thanks

Comment: No, if one (or more or all) device can't be open because of privileges it simply won't be in the list, no error will be returned. From man page: "*..Note that there may be network devices that cannot be opened by the process calling pcap_findalldevs(), because, for example, that process might not have sufficient privileges to open them for capturing; if so, those devices will not appear on the list...*"

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. I'll test with heightened privileges.

Comment: That's the answer. I moved out the above code into a console application to test. $sudo myapp <-- works as expected

Comment: You might want to answer your own question, so this question shows up as having been answered, with the answer being "you need sufficient privileges".  (Note that "sufficient privileges", on \*BSD, OS X, and jailbroken iOS, means "sufficient privileges to open a `/dev/bpf*` device; if those devices are made readable by a user or group other than root, that user or users in that group have sufficient privileges.  Wireshark installs a script to put the user into a group that's given those privileges, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in Xcode and got it to work. You're most likely encountering a permission issue. If you're using Xcode, go to your project's scheme to edit and then under "Debug Process As", select root. You will be prompted to enter your password to run.